# What's wrong with the application of Bernoulli's equation here?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

Here, taking line $13$ as datum and applying Bernoulli's equation at point $1$ and $2$ yields the following equation:

$$(P_o + \rho gh) + 0 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 = P_o + \rho g h + 0$$

[image]

Above equation implies $v$, the velocity at point $1$ equals zero! This probably shouldn't be the case here.

Sorry, if this is something very basic, but please guide me where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the diagram, $h$ and $H$ are different symbols measuring different things. In your equation you have $h$ twice.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$ should occur on both sides.

Comment: @alephzero I have nothing to do with point 3 (in the figure) and hence $H$, only applying equation at $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @Gert Why, isn't the liquid stationary at point 2

Comment: No, you're right actually. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar unanswered question on the site just got answered, here is the
[link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/631467/i-read-about-the-difference-between-static-and-dynamic-pressure-in-fluids-in-the#) to that.